# Is maximum resolution supported by the computer = maximum resolution visible in Graphic Settings?

Tags: windows-7, display, graphics-card, resolution

I have **Asus G31 m-vs** . **G31/33 family Chipset**. Chip Type: **Intel GMA 3100**. *No additional Graphic Card.* 
I use a CRT monitor and my resolution is set to 1080*768. When I right click on
 `desktop--->Graphic Properties--->Graphic Settings`. I find that the maximum resolution available in the dropdown is **1152*864**. Although the Asus's site says that *G31 m-vs -supports D-Sub with max. resolution up to 2048x1536 @ 60Hz* I am not sure if I will be able to set resolution to 1920*1080 if I get a bigger monitor since I only have **1152*864** available in graphic settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum resolution capability of the Graphics Card & connected Monitor are two separate limits.

If the card can do 2048x1536 yet the monitor can only do 1152x864, then that is what Windows will tell you is the current maximum. Windows can 'see' the monitor's spec & will not allow 'unsafe' resolutions.

(It can be forced, but that wouldn't answer your question)

Comment: Presumably this only applies to plug 'n' play monitors?

Comment: I wasn't aware there was any other type, tbh - not the 'windows-branded' plug & play, but just the concept of any device not being able to tell the computer what its capabilities are.

Comment: The monitor I am planning on buying has max resolution of 1920*1080(16:9). Do you think I will face any problems setting resolution to 1920*1080 with this new monitor? Asus G31 seems to support 2048x1536 (4:3).

Comment: I remember displays that didn't provide this info (showing my age). I was surprised when I checked and found that the [Display Data Channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel) standard dates back to 1994. So I guess all displays not in museums will provide this info :)

Comment: @DavidPostill  :-)

Comment: @Arbaaz - so long as you have the most recent drivers [though they're 5 years old so you should already have them], it should be fine - see http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-030332.htm

Comment: That's a relief. Btw do anyone of you know what difference does does it make if resolution is 16:9 or 4:3? I mean they are both same rations right? I know one is wide screen another is not but it makes no sense to a layman because 16:9=4:3

Comment: 16:9 != 4:3  ...4*4:3*3 = 16:9 ...not 4*4:4*3, which would be 16:12

Comment: How much is this going to hamper the picture quality? Since G1 supports support 2048x1536 (4:3) while the new monitor is 1920*1080 (16:4)

Comment: I don't understand the question. How would going to a higher resolution monitor hamper your picture quality? Not that I've used anything with such low rez in years, but I can only remember how fabulous it was when I first went from an old 21" 1920x1440 CRT to a 27" 2560x1440 LCD

Comment: No not higher resolution. The fact that my the new monitor will be 16:9 while my graphics are 4:3. Does it mean that I will have problem setting resolution

Comment: 27" 2560x1440 LCD lol that shows I am still living in the stone age.

Comment: see my earlier comment re: latest drivers

Comment: @Tetsujin I got the new monitor. I had absolutely no trouble at all setting resolution to 1920 x 1080. Infact I did not even have to set it myself. It was already there. Cheers !